# Wally Bought A Dog

Tags: percentages

Wally bought a dog. There was a $25\%$ discount because it was a sale day, a $10\%$ further discount off of the result because it was a big dog, and a $5\%$ further discount off of that result because he did not use a credit card. (In other words, the discounts were taken successively. A $\$8$ item would be discounted down to $\$6$, then to $\$5.40$, then to $\$5.13$) He paid $\$1385.10$, which of course included the $8\%$ sales tax.

What was the original price of the dog (before tax and discounts)?)

Comment: Hint: Mark $x=$ the original price. What is the paid price, in terms of $x$?

Comment: Dollar signs carry a special meaning to the formatting on this site. If you want actual dollar signs, you have to write `\$` instead of just `$`.

Comment: Broad hint: you are basically multiplying by $0.75$, than by $0.9$, than by $0.95$ to get $5.13$. It needs to be reversed. So you just divide by the same numbers your number $1385.10$   Then you have to handle the sales tax. That should not be a problem: when you add some percentage like taxes (8%) you can simply multiply by $1.08$ to add the tax, and you can divide (by $1.08$) to reverse.  Hope our hints were helpful.